# Tensorflow: How to gather from indices along inner dimension

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorflow2.0

I have a 4d tensor output for an object detector that outputs per-pixel, per class box predictions, i.e. Shape H x W x C x 6, where the innermost 6 wide dimension is box parameter for that class. Now, when computing loss, I want to update only the predictions from the ground truth class. To do this, I'd like to have a tensor with shape H x W whose elements are the ground truth class index. This tensor is then used to extract the relevant class only from the input, outputting a tensor with H x W x 6. I know this should be possible using gather or gather_nd but I can't get the parameters right to get the desired output. Plus I'm confused about the purpose of the batch_dims parameter for gather_nd, that may be relevant though to solving this. Any suggestions on how I can properly use these or some other tf function to achieve this result?

Comment: Can you clarify what the box parameters are? Would probably also help if you could have a simple example (e.g. 2x2x2x6) of the model output and what the desired tensor for the loss in that example

Comment: x, y, length, width, cos angle, sin angle, but these could be any 6 values. I realized I misworded it, there are not 6 dimensions for box parameters but rather the innermost dimension is 6 wide and contains the parameters